# how do i use list comprehensions to print a list of all possible dimensions of a cuboid in python?

Tags: python, list

You are given three integers x,y and z representing the dimensions of a cuboid along with an integer n. Print a list of all possible coordinates given by (i,j,k) on a 3D grid where the sum of  i+j+k is not equal to n. Here,0<=i<=x; 0<=j<=y;0<=k<=z. Please use list comprehensions rather than multiple loops, as a learning exercise.

I'm unable to solve this problem. Could anyone help me out with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYwxDoMwEAR7XjHpjHxNApS8BKVIEeBAOpBFgfm840DBljO7u8ZtXKxKaReicAhGy0uohFpoijWoba5zKkzCXNIvAUWN8LHh63Y8z4tON40nLcj5m/k2x9XXPp/4PPFZPlrsXab0Aw)

```
x, y, z, n = 2, 3, 4, 5
print([(i, j, k) for i in range(x + 1) for j in range(y + 1)
    for k in range(z + 1) if i + j + k != n])
```

Output:

```
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 3), (0, 0, 4), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 3), (0, 2, 0), (0, 2, 1), (0, 2, 2), (0, 2, 4), (0, 3, 0), (0, 3, 1), (0, 3, 3), (0, 3, 4), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 2), (1, 0, 3), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 4), (1, 2, 0), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 0), (1, 3, 2), (1, 3, 3), (1, 3, 4), (2, 0, 0), (2, 0, 1), (2, 0, 2), (2, 0, 4), (2, 1, 0), (2, 1, 1), (2, 1, 3), (2, 1, 4), (2, 2, 0), (2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 3), (2, 2, 4), (2, 3, 1), (2, 3, 2), (2, 3, 3), (2, 3, 4)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    x, y, z, n = (int(input().strip()) for _ in range(4))
    print([[i,j,k] for i in range(x+1) for j in range(y+1) for k in range(z+1) if i+j+k!=n ])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print([[a, b, c] for a in range(x + 1) for b in range(y + 1) for c in range(z + 1) if a + b + c != n])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to print **a list of lists** of all possible combinations of (i, j, k) for the given x, y, z values where the sum of i + j + k is not equal to n you can try:

---

```
print([[i, j, k] for i in range(x + 1) for j in range(y + 1)
    for k in range(z + 1) if i + j + k != n])
```

Comment: Please extend your answer with sample input data and output generated with the program above, explaining how it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since the answer specifically asks for list comprehensions, aren't all of these technically wrong? I just tweaked the currently highest-upvoted answer to use list comprehension.

newlist=[[i, j, k] for i in range(x + 1) for j in range(y + 1)
for k in range(z + 1) if i + j + k != n]
print(newlist)

Answer (score -1):

if **name** == '**main**':

```
x=int(input())
y=int(input())
z=int(input())
n=int(input())
ans=[] #should be assigned to a list.
for i in range(x+1):
  for j in range(y+1):
    for k in range(z+1):


       if(i+j+k)!=n:
          ans.append([i,j,k])

print(ans)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).